# Angular Kendo Grid with k-rebind not deep watching it's options object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

I have an Angular Kendo Grid referencing it's options object with `k-options` and `k-rebind`...

```
<kendo-grid k-data-source="data" k-options="options" k-rebind="options"></kendo-grid>
```

When I change the column titles in the referenced options object the grid doesn't notice the change and therefore doesn't fire `k-rebind` on the next digest.

How can I get it to watch the options object deeply and notice these important changes?

Working [code pen](http://codepen.io/hally9k/pen/BoQMaN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $scope.changeColTitles = function(){
    $scope.a++;
    $scope.b++;
  }
```

If a scope variable is changed in a controller, the changed value won't be get reflected where ever it is used. A watch must be kept and do the corresponding logic inside.

And for your problem, you don't need to keep either watch. The following line of code should resolve the problem. CodePen is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYbVOe?editors=101).

```
$scope.changeColTitles = function(){
    $scope.options.columns[0].title = 'col ' + ++$scope.a;
    $scope.options.columns[1].title =  'col ' + ++$scope.b;
  }
```

Comment: Plus a point for working solution but I don't understand your explanation very well... Could you clarify?

Comment: Oh sorry for that!. Usually if a scope variable is changed, the angular digest cycle will reflect the value in the view only but in controller it only checks if the variable has any watch to be executed... So in your case:  when ever *a* and *b* are changed, that changed values are not really got reflected into columns directly: You can update those columns in two ways, first one is the way I mentioned in the answer and second one is $scope.$watch('a',function(){ })

Comment: You can update those columns in two ways, first one is the way I mentioned in the answer and second one is 
$scope.changeColTitles = function(){
    $scope.a++;
    $scope.b++;
  } 

$scope.$watch('a',function(){
 $scope.options.columns[0].title = 'col ' + $scope.a;
})

$scope.$watch('b',function(){
 $scope.options.columns[0].title = 'col ' + $scope.b;
})

I hope that I m clear somewhat!

Comment: You should edit your answer rather than put code snippets into your comments... It's illegible on a phone for example.